# How to enable DRI3 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, graphics, intel-graphics, vulkan

I'm trying to learn Vulkan, so I install the Mesa Vulkan drivers and development files.

I downloaded some examples.
I compiled the examples and tried to execute one. But when I run the file from terminal, it gave one warning and error:

```
WARNING: Haswell Vulkan support is incomplete
Error: No DRI3 support
```

I ask it from the person who wrote the example program, he said I have to enable the DRI3 for the running program. How can I do it in Ubuntu 16.04?

When I open the file "/etc/X11/xorg.conf", I see this:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "Default Card 0"
    BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
EndSection
```

What I need to do?

My environment: I'm using Intel Core i5 and Intel Haswell GPU.

Answer (score 4):

Open this file: `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` as root and make the device section look like this

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"
   Option      "DRI"    "3"
EndSection
```

This is from the [Arch wiki for Vulkan](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Vulkan).

Comment: When i try to open and save it as root with gedit, it gives this error: Could not find the file “/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf”

Comment: If it does not exist, you can just make it. Then reboot.

Comment: is /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/ dir used on Ubuntu?

Comment: I think dir for Ubuntu should be /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/

Comment: You should create the /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/ directory first if it does not exist. /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/ is there for system vendor options and not for custom user configuration. Read "man xorg.conf" for details.